# How to create two variant of an app from same code base in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React Native and createed a simple app now I want to create two variant of an app `Development` and `Production`.Now What I want to achieve in these two variants are as follows:

- Each variant should have a different name.
- Each variant should have a different package-name.
- Each variant should have a different url that it pulls data from.

Below is an error  I am getting

```
Error: Activity class {com.myapp.dev/com.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

This is how I set up build variant in `build.gradle` file.

```
android{

    flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.awesome.project.dev'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
    }
    prod {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.awesome.project'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
    }
 }

}
```

Someone let me know how can I achieve desired functionality.